# When did Pontius Pilate rule?

Tags: ancient-rome, bible

The most precise years for his rule I've seen is 26/27 AD to 36/37 AD.

Has someone gotten it down to at least a precise year?

Comment: [Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786)  What is wrong with the answer in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontius_Pilate#Role_as_governor_of_Judaea)? (which matches all the results I found) What is the source you're citing?  Kind of pointless for us to do research and come up with the same information you've already found.  How much effort has that source put into understanding all the complexity in calendars across the millennia?

Comment: As a quick perusal of the WP page linked in the comment above will make clear, the problem in cases such as these isn't so much that people don't have it figured to a precise year as it is that said people don't agree with each other as to what that year that is.

Comment: That IS a precise year. Whether it's one or the other depends on exactly which calendar is in use when and when those switched. That's always a problem with dating things in the past, calendars switched frequently and the exact dates on which are often hard to determine.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is when you consider the start of the year, considering the many options of the [Seleucid Era](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seleucid_era), and the many calendars that used this Era in the Middle East by this time. Do not think an Era is a calendar! Also, consider that the Roman calendar was NOT in use in Judaea by this time yet and this adds a layer of complexity but allows us to pinpoint this range.

Comment: Also note that many classical cultures -- including the Romans and Greeks -- used inclusive counting, so that a period of ten years by their reckoning would be nine in ours.

Answer (score 0):

At that time they were counting the years in the of reign of the Roman Emperor. Josephus said he was the Roman governor of Judea for 10 years when Tiberius was the Emperor.
(in the 14th year of Tiberius to the 24th year of Tiberius)
Marcellus took over when the Roman governor of Syria ordered him back to Rome after the incident with the armed Samaritans near Mount Gerizim.

**SOURCES**

JA Book 18 Chapter 4

[image: Original Limestone Inscription]

Original Limestone Inscription

Comment: This would benefit from a supporting source or two.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).